# Are these histograms stacked or overlapping?

Tags: particle-physics, statistics

How do I read these histograms because the interpretation seems ambiguous.

[image: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/the-higgs-particle/holiday-higgs-hints-confidence-inspiring-or-not/]

https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/the-higgs-particle/holiday-higgs-hints-confidence-inspiring-or-not/

Are they stacked or overlapping?

So we established that the first one was stacked. Is the one below overlapping?

[image]

http://cds.cern.ch/record/1312375/plots

Surely the delivered data cannot be less than the recorded data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are stacked (in your terminology).  The uppermost dark line is the sum of the background and one of the 3 possible signals, so you can compare it with the data.  The 3 $M_H$ values are alternatives and putting them on one plot to give 3 histograms saves space, at the cost of possible confusion.

Comment: I see, but in general it can be either way? Either stacked or overlapping and one has to figure it out? I added another plot which I think is overlapping.

Comment: Yes, that is overlapping. The visible green area shows the luminosity delivered but not recorded. There is no fixed rule (and arguably the caption should explain better) but basically the obviously sensible interpretation is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

This must be before the mass of the Higgs was established at 125GeV, and the channel was examined for a Higgs signal. You should give a link for the plot.

It is not clear what you mean by stacked.

The colors say everything.

The red backround is generating artificial monte Carlo events where there is no Higgs going to the channel searched for , in this energy region and this is the basis for comparison  with how an 150 GeV Higgs  with that decay would look in the data,if it existed, and alternatively  an 190 GeV,as a third hypothesis. The 125GeV hypothesis is the closest to the data (points with error bars) and this is just a hopeful  indication, because 1.5 sigma is not a signal after all.

By 2013 the indications  for 125 GeV from a number of channels,  have become  a certainty with more data.

Comment: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/the-higgs-particle/holiday-higgs-hints-confidence-inspiring-or-not/

Comment: By "stacked" i mean whether any of the blue, orange or purple color hides behind the red region, in which case if would be overlapping or no colors obstruct one another which would make it stacked.